# Permission Denied While Running Script

Tags: python, linux, bash, sudo

I am attempting to run a script from the shairport-sync service with this command:

```
run_this_after_play_ends = "/home/pi/Watson/testmicend.sh"
```

/home/pi/Watson/testmicend.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
python3 /home/pi/Watson/mprobot.py
```

Gives this error:

```
  from gopigo import *
Jul 27 11:02:39 raspberrypi shairport-sync[3923]:   File "/home/pi/Watson/gopigo.py", line 60, in <module>
Jul 27 11:02:39 raspberrypi shairport-sync[3923]:     bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
Jul 27 11:02:39 raspberrypi shairport-sync[3923]: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I then added this to script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo python3 /home/pi/Watson/mprobot.py
```

Added shiarport-sync to sudo group

```
sudo usermod -aG sudo shairport-sync
```

Modified etc/sudoers using visudo

```
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
shairport-sync ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:/home/pi/Watson/testmicend.sh
```

Running script gets:

```
Jul 27 11:08:14 raspberrypi shairport-sync[3923]: We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Jul 27 11:08:14 raspberrypi shairport-sync[3923]: Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:
Jul 27 11:08:14 raspberrypi shairport-sync[3923]:     #1) Respect the privacy of others.
Jul 27 11:08:14 raspberrypi shairport-sync[3923]:     #2) Think before you type.
Jul 27 11:08:14 raspberrypi shairport-sync[3923]:     #3) With great power comes great responsibility.
Jul 27 11:08:14 raspberrypi shairport-sync[3923]: sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
Jul 27 11:08:14 raspberrypi sudo[5271]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): conversation failed
Jul 27 11:08:14 raspberrypi sudo[5271]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): auth could not identify password for [shairport-sync]
```

I've also tried passing password in the script but that also failed

Comment: You need to run `testmicend.sh` with `sudo`, not `python3`.

Comment: A workaround would be a small c-program that does the same as `testmicend.sh`. The advantage is that you can set the suid bit on the compiled `testmicend` c-program which runs it as root without password prompt (on the python script you can't set the suid bit or in detail you can set it but Linux will ignore it).

Comment: Try the following in `sudoers`: `shairport-sync ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` at the bottom of the file and then `sudo su - shairport-sync` followed by `sudo id`. If that works, replace the last `ALL` by your script.